# Link for printing image

Tags: javascript, html, web

Actually I need a bit of Java Script, but I am definitely not good at it. So I would really need your help.

My problem is, that I would need a script, which saves me the url from an id to a variable and outputs the variable something like this: `<a href="+ variable +">LINK</a>`.

Note, that the ID, where I would like to get the link from, is somewhere in the page and the script likely at the bottom.

EXAMPLE OF WHAT I MEAN:

```
<div id="http://www.example.com" name="url">
  <p>Some content</p>
</div>
.
.
.
.
<a href="+ variable +">LINK</a>
.
.
.
<script>
   variable = getIdWhereNameIsURL;
   ....
</script>
```

Would really appreciate your help!

Comment: Do you want a pure javascript solution or does jQuery work? How is this related to PHP?

Comment: That doesn't seem too.... eficient, are you sure is the only way? That logic could improve a lot. For example, what about using hidden inputs to store URLs instead of elements ids?

Comment: Sorry, no relation to php...

Comment: Well, actually I have embedded an image and I need the url of it at the bottom, of the code. It doesn't matter for me how I get it, but it should be pretty simple. Performance shouldn't be an issue, since this would be the only JS used in the webpage.

Comment: Umm... with the current logic, it's gonna be a very frustrating procedure. Where is this --id="http://www.example.com" name="url"-- comming from? from a database?

Comment: Yeah, more or less. It is a wordpress site and it is printed with php to the code. And no, I have no access to the URL since there is no relation to this specific url anymore at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `id="http://www.example.com"` may seems odd, but it should be OK per the [HTML 5 specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute). It is also unusual to have a NAME attribute for a DIV element.

Second, it will be easier to specify another id for your LINK, perhaps something like `<a id="link_id">LINK</a>`.

Then, you can have the below in your script block

```
var theDIV = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
// here assuming it is the first DIV, otherwise, loop through the elements
// document.getElementsByName("url")[0].id may not work
if (theDIV.name == "url") {
  var theLink = document.getElementById("link_id");
  theLink.href = theDIV.id; 
}
```