# Get Image URL from site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

currently I am working on a print button for images which are shown over an overlay. The button itself is already displayed, but I would need the link to the image. The problem is, that there are more links/overlays of this type and that I am really bad in javascript.

Also, the code from the overlay is at the very bottom of the site, so I would need to get the URL from above.

The code, which is clicked, looks like this (where .$largebild. is the url of the image from the database -> I have no access to it at the  bottom)

```
echo '
<div>For the menu of the week click
    <span class="zoom-enabled"  zoom="<div class=\'overlayplakat\' id=\''.$largebild.'\' name=\'nameOfElement\' style=\'background: url('.$largebild.') no-repeat center center; background-size: contain;\'></div>"> here!</span>
</div>';
```

What I have planned is, that the script function should get the id, which is the url, where the name is the element which was clicked.

The problem of all that is, that it should be one function for the print button to know where it should get the link and print it like that:

```
<div id="overlay-print">
    <a id="link" href="javascript:getImageLink()" target="_blank">
        <i class="icons overlay-button-size">&#xE8AD;</i>
    </a>
</div>
```

I thought there about parameters and probably a help function to identify which element was clicked.

I would be so greatful for help. If you need anything else, just ask.

PS: You should know, that I have posted the same yesterday, but yesterday I only needed one link which worked fine for me. Here is the link: [Link for printing image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32673934/link-for-printing-image)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to pass parameters and you want to inline your javascript like your post suggest I think you have at least two options:

1. Use the DOM structure to figure out what image you want to print.
2. Mark the appropriate image when it's clicked and print the image with the marker when "print" is clicked.

For option 1, if you have a DOM like:

```
.div
   #url.overlayplakat
   %button.print
```

When the user clicks the print button you can make your javascript search of an adjacent `.overlayplakat` class pull its ID to get the printable url.

Like so:

```
function getImageLink() {
   var url = $(this).siblings('.overlayplakat').attr('id');
   return url;
}
```

Comment: Thats a possibility.

But what about handling the url with a function to another one with parameters.

The second function would change the link, the first one hands over the link. But is it possible to use PHP in Javascript in order to hand over the link to the other script?

Comment: There are many ways to do this type of thing. I'm having a hard time following you though. Maybe ask another, more narrow, question?

Comment: Well, as you can see above, I have this <div> where within is I get the URL from PHP. There I would like to call a function with a parameter (the URL is the parameter). 

So now the question: Is it possible that I can hand it over like this: `javascript:function(<?php echo .$largebild. ?>)`


If it is possible, I would only need this function for setting the image url (href).